# Python 3 Game Bug: Holding down the enter key

Tags: python

I have another question related to this game, here it is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545444/python-3-game-bug-message-repeating

I made a game thats a knock off of Cookie Clicker (just for coding practice!). And I ran into a problem where the user can hold down the enter key, and get coins really fast. I'd like to prevent that. here is my code:

```
coin = 0
keepgoing = True

while keepgoing == True:
        print('You have ' + str(coin) + ' cmd-coins' )
        response = input('Press enter to get a coin!')
        if response == 'q':
                keepgoing = False
                print('Thanks for playing!')
coin = coin + 1
```

Comment: Press enter to get a coin... you hit enter really fast and you get coins really fast... uhh, what is supposed to be happening? (Shouldn't the line incrementing coin be within the loop?)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Could his problem be that he wants someone to have to repeatedly press down the `Enter` key, and currently the easiest way to win the game is simply to hold the key down?

Comment: Also, slight nitpick: `while keepgoing == True` is normally written `while keepgoing`. (== True is implied by the while keyword in the first place.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Take a look at my answer to see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, i would like the user to press the enter key repeatedly instead of just holding it down.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a rather "gimmicky" solution to your problem, which works *to an extent* but definitely isn't flawless. Based on your compiler you may have to change the conditional value for `start-end` such that it is a value which allows you to static press as fast as humanly possible without breaking but not allow the user to hold the `enter` key. For me in WingIde, 0.03 is the optimal value.

Were you to import a module such as Pygame you would find this sort of game much easier to make.

```
import time

coins = 0
keepgoing = True
end = -1

while keepgoing:
    print('You have ' + str(coins) + ' cmd-coins' )
    response = input('Press enter to get a coin!')
    start = time.time()
    if start-end < 0.03:
        print ("Don't hold down the Enter key you cheater!")
        keepgoing = False
    if response == 'q':
        print('Thanks for Playing!')
        keepgoing = False
    coins = coins + 1
    end = time.time()
```

**NOTE**: *This solution is for Python 3, for < Python 3 you'll have to substitute `raw_input()` for `input()`. Also, I wouldn't advise trying to use it on an online compiler.*

Answer (score 0):

G Force dog,
You could change your game a bit by making a few changes till someone or I figure out a good solution(Mom gave orders to go to bed). Till we don't find a solution, use this code which isn't exactly a solution.

```
coins = 0
real = 0
while real == 0:
    if True:
        print('You have ' + str(coins) + ' cmd-coins' )
        response = input('Press c to get a coin, then press ENTER!')
        if response == 'c' or response == 'C':
            coins = coins + 1
        if response == 'q':
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            real = 1
```

And 2 things:-

1. Nice answer Yeniaul! Good try!
2. Elizion, nice try but your method isn't working. But it is a good idea.
   I have used time too, but it seems that when one presses ENTER key for a long time, it just comes out on the screen all together.

I think I do have somewhat of an idea forming... if we make another while loop, after importing 'time', with a condition which makes the loop active every 2 seconds by assigning a variable 'time.clock()' and when its value is a multiple of 2, it activates! 
Got it? I know what to do, but can't seem to put it in code. See if you can, reader(especially Elizion and Yeniaul)

Answer (score -1):

Try using time.sleep(seconds of delay) for slowdown
So you could do

```
coin = 0
keepgoing = True

while keepgoing == True:
        time.sleep(0.25)
        print('You have ' + str(coin) + ' cmd-coins' )
        response = input('Press enter to get a coin!')
        if response == 'q':
                keepgoing = False
                print('Thanks for playing!')
coin = coin + 1
```

This would make it a quarter-second delay before they could get another coin.

Comment: The game would still be broken. Holding down the `Enter` key would still be the easiest way to accumulate coins.

Comment: You definitely did not try this code before you posted it.

Comment: That's hardly a solution.

Comment: Plus, just your code throws an error when pressing enter. i get "Unexpected EOF"

Comment: @Yeniaul Your "answer" contains errors thoughtlessly copied and pasted from the OP's question, and your issue with Elizion's code is that **you didn't read his answer**: it only works on Python 3 and you have to adjust the code to run it on Python 2.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to fix my problem, but i have already considered that and it is not the solution i am looking for.